# Output a specific part of an array by its key

Tags: php, arrays

How can I output a specific part of an array, just by it's key?
Or rather how can I change the array so it ONLY contains elements with a specific key?

My array `$postarray` has several elements and the keys: title, date, filepath.

```
array(1) {
   [0]=> array(3) {
      ["date"]=> string(10) "2014-10-21"
      ["title"]=> string(75) "Improving Your Information Architecture With Card Sorting A Beginners Guide"
      ["filepath"]=> string(75) "improving-your-information-architecture-with-card-sorting-a-beginners-guide"
   }
}
```

I want to create an array that only stores the `filepath` part. So to test I am trying a var_dump of just `filepath` key:

```
var_dump($postarray['filepath']);
```

But I get an `undefined index` error, just when I var _dump. Let alone when I try and create a new array variable with just this data.

Comment: Try with `var_dump($postarray[0]['filepath']);`

Comment: @Gautam3164 that works, however the data I provided above is just a shortened example. What happens when I want to output all my data? Which can be any number of array items.

Comment: `foreach($postarray as $value) { echo $value['filepath']; }`

Answer (score 4):

You have a multi-dimensional array, or an "array of arrays".  You need to iterate through the outer array:

```
foreach ($postarray as $innerarray) {
    var_dump($innerarray['filepath']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing [0] in your code. You can access any of them by using it's key.

```
$postarray[0]['date'];
$postarray[0]['title'];
$postarray[0]['filepath'];
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a multi dimensional array.

In case of it . You have to call like

echo  `$postarray[0]['filepath']` to get the `filepath`